# WebView inside ScrollView calling refreshControl everytime swiping up React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, webview, scrollview, pull-to-refresh

I have a WebView inside a ScrollView on a React Native app. The ScrollView has the refreshControl prop so I can refresh the WebView when I reach the top of the app.

Here's the problem: I scroll the WebView without a problem, but whenever I swipe up to go to the top of the page, doesn't matter if I'm on the end, the middle or the beginning of the page, the refreshControl is always triggered.

The RefreshControl is triggered when the scrollY: 0 and the scrollY is always 0, because what is being scrolled isn't the ScrollView but the WebView, so the ScrollView is always at scrollY: 0.

I already tried the scrollEnabled prop on both WebView and ScrollView but none worked.

Here's how the code looks right now:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView
      contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
        />
      }
    >
      <WebView
        ref="webview"
        source={{uri: initialUrl}}
      />
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

I've removed all the props to try to start over, but I always get the same problem. On iOS it's working alright, without this issue.

Yes, I do have other stuff inside this mother View.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but using the FlatList. Try to remove the `contentContainerStyle`, more specifically the `flex: 1`.
In this way, worked for me!

Comment: Which style to you have on the webview ? If I remove the contentContainerStyle, my webview is not displayed any more